# what are some good fonts to combine with Forza?

Tags: typography, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I have a client who is overusing Forza, for all headers, body, etc. I'd really like to mix it up but I am not good with fonts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Forza for body copy and maybe something even more punchy like Tungsten: https://www.typography.com/fonts/tungsten/overview/ for headers